# Identify strings while removing substrings in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a dictionary of words with their frequencies as follows.

```
mydictionary = {'yummy tim tam':3, 'milk':2, 'chocolates':5, 'biscuit pudding':3, 'sugar':2}
```

I have a set of strings (removed punctuation marks) as follows.

```
recipes_book = "For todays lesson we will show you how to make biscuit pudding using 
yummy tim tam milk and rawsugar"
```

In the above string I need output only "biscuit pudding", "yummy tim tam" and "milk" by referring the dictionary. NOT sugar, because its rawsugar in the string.

However, the code I am currently using outputs sugar as well.

```
mydictionary = {'yummy tim tam':3, 'milk':2, 'chocolates':5, 'biscuit pudding':3, 'sugar':2}
recipes_book = "For today's lesson we will show you how to make biscuit pudding using yummy tim tam milk and rawsugar"
searcher = re.compile(r'{}'.format("|".join(mydictionary.keys())), flags=re.I | re.S)

for match in searcher.findall(recipes_book):
    print(match)
```

How to avoid using sub-strings like that and only consider one full tokens such as 'milk'. Please help me.

Comment: use word boundary `\b`

Comment: Why did you accept an answer if it does not work for you? Update the question since it is the same issue you [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544114/detect-substrings-using-regex-in-python?noredirect=1). Word boundaries are only a part of the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code with regex word boundary:

```
mydictionary = {'yummy tim tam':3, 'milk':2, 'chocolates':5, 'biscuit pudding':3, 'sugar':2}
recipes_book = "For today's lesson we will show you how to make biscuit pudding using yummy tim tam milk and rawsugar"
searcher = re.compile(r'{}'.format("|".join(map(lambda x: r'\b{}\b'.format(x), mydictionary.keys()))), flags=re.I | re.S)

for match in searcher.findall(recipes_book):
    print(match)
```

Output:

```
biscuit pudding
yummy tim tam
milk
```

Comment: You may also remove `re.S` as it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundary '\b'. In simple words

```
recipes_book = "For todays lesson we will show you how to make biscuit pudding using 
yummy tim tam milk and rawsugar"

>>> re.findall(r'(?is)(\bchocolates\b|\bbiscuit pudding\b|\bsugar\b|\byummy tim tam\b|\bmilk\b)',recipes_book)
['biscuit pudding', 'yummy tim tam', 'milk']
```

Comment: Without hard coding my dictionary keys in `re.findall` is there any easy way of doing it?

Comment: I am just illustrating the use of `\b` word boundary here, you can edit accordingly, just check @Delimitry answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One more way using `re.escape`.
More info regarding [re.escape here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) !!!

```
import re

mydictionary = {'yummy tim tam':3, 'milk':2, 'chocolates':5, 'biscuit pudding':3, 'sugar':2}
recipes_book = "For today's lesson we will show you how to make biscuit pudding using yummy tim tam milk and rawsugar"

val_list = []

for i in mydictionary.keys():
    tmp_list = []
    regex_tmp = r'\b'+re.escape(str(i))+r'\b'
    tmp_list = re.findall(regex_tmp,recipes_book)
    val_list.extend(tmp_list)

print val_list
```

**Output:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\python.exe" C:/Users/punddin/PycharmProjects/demo/demo.py
['yummy tim tam', 'biscuit pudding', 'milk']
```